# how to make slot from staff shift nodejs mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a salon booking system. Salon has multiple staff members, each staff has its own shift like this. (I break shift because of lunch break if it's not right please let me know your thought thanks)

```
shift: [
  {
    id: 1,
    day: 'Mon',
    status: true,
    shift: [
      {startTime: '08:00 am', endTime: '01:00 pm'},
      {startTime: '02:00 pm', endTime: '05:00 pm'},
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    day: 'Tue',
    status: true,
    shift: [
      {startTime: '08:00 am', endTime: '01:00 pm'},
      {startTime: '02:00 pm', endTime: '05:00 pm'},
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    day: 'Wed',
    status: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    day: 'Thu',
    status: true,
    shift: [
      {startTime: '08:00 am', endTime: '01:00 pm'},
      {startTime: '02:00 pm', endTime: '05:00 pm'},
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    day: 'Fri',
    status: true,
    shift: [
      {startTime: '08:00 am', endTime: '01:00 pm'},
      {startTime: '02:00 pm', endTime: '05:00 pm'},
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    day: 'Sat',
    status: false,
    shift: [],
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    day: 'Sun',
    status: false,
    shift: [],
  },
]
```

now my goal is to send slots to the user and if user book any slot then how to mark booked slots and not to send booked slots when another ask for slots. I am using express.js MongoDB for this project thanks.

Q1) how to convert shift to the slot for the user?

Q2) how to mark booked if user book any slot?

Q3) how to not send booked slot if the user asks, send only available slot?

Answer (score 0):

data

```
db={
  "employees": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      shift: [
        {
          id: 1,
          day: "Mon",
          status: true,
          shift: [
            {
              startTime: "08:00 am",
              endTime: "09:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "9:00 am",
              endTime: "10:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "10:00 am",
              endTime: "11:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "11:00 am",
              endTime: "12:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "12:00 pm",
              endTime: "01:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "02:00 pm",
              endTime: "03:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "03:00 pm",
              endTime: "04:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "04:00 pm",
              endTime: "05:00 pm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          day: "Tue",
          status: true,
          shift: [
            {
              startTime: "08:00 am",
              endTime: "09:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "9:00 am",
              endTime: "10:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "10:00 am",
              endTime: "11:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "11:00 am",
              endTime: "12:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "12:00 pm",
              endTime: "01:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "02:00 pm",
              endTime: "03:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "03:00 pm",
              endTime: "04:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "04:00 pm",
              endTime: "05:00 pm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          day: "Wed",
          status: true,
          
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          day: "Thu",
          status: true,
          shift: [
            {
              startTime: "08:00 am",
              endTime: "09:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "9:00 am",
              endTime: "10:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "10:00 am",
              endTime: "11:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "11:00 am",
              endTime: "12:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "12:00 pm",
              endTime: "01:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "02:00 pm",
              endTime: "03:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "03:00 pm",
              endTime: "04:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "04:00 pm",
              endTime: "05:00 pm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          day: "Fri",
          status: true,
          shift: [
            {
              startTime: "08:00 am",
              endTime: "09:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "9:00 am",
              endTime: "10:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "10:00 am",
              endTime: "11:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "11:00 am",
              endTime: "12:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "12:00 pm",
              endTime: "01:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "02:00 pm",
              endTime: "03:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "03:00 pm",
              endTime: "04:00 pm"
            },
            {
              startTime: "04:00 pm",
              endTime: "05:00 pm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          day: "Sat",
          status: false,
          shift: [],
          
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          day: "Sun",
          status: false,
          shift: [],
          
        },
        
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bookings": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "employee_id": 1,
      "day_id": 2,
      "slot": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "employee_id": 1,
      "day_id": 5,
      "slot": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

aggregate

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$shift"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$shift.shift",
      includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "bookings",
      let: {
        arrayIndex: "$arrayIndex",
        shift_id: "$shift.id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$shift_id",
                    "$day_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$arrayIndex",
                    "$slot"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bookings"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "bookings": {
        "$size": 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arrayIndex": NumberLong(0),
    "bookings": [],
    "shift": {
      "day": "Mon",
      "id": 1,
      "shift": {
        "endTime": "01:00 pm",
        "startTime": "08:00 am"
      },
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arrayIndex": NumberLong(1),
    "bookings": [],
    "shift": {
      "day": "Mon",
      "id": 1,
      "shift": {
        "endTime": "05:00 pm",
        "startTime": "02:00 pm"
      },
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arrayIndex": NumberLong(1),
    "bookings": [],
    "shift": {
      "day": "Tue",
      "id": 2,
      "shift": {
        "endTime": "05:00 pm",
        "startTime": "02:00 pm"
      },
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arrayIndex": NumberLong(0),
    "bookings": [],
    "shift": {
      "day": "Thu",
      "id": 4,
      "shift": {
        "endTime": "01:00 pm",
        "startTime": "08:00 am"
      },
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arrayIndex": NumberLong(1),
    "bookings": [],
    "shift": {
      "day": "Thu",
      "id": 4,
      "shift": {
        "endTime": "05:00 pm",
        "startTime": "02:00 pm"
      },
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arrayIndex": NumberLong(0),
    "bookings": [],
    "shift": {
      "day": "Fri",
      "id": 5,
      "shift": {
        "endTime": "01:00 pm",
        "startTime": "08:00 am"
      },
      "status": true
    }
  }
]
```

If you want to ask how to use this data structure to query specific data, please give the **query parameters** and **expected output**, I will add the query function.

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YIuIsaklYdK)

Comment: shift break into slot e.g with 1 hour interval 08:00, 09:00, 10:00, 11:00.....

Comment: I update my answer by changing data structure